# JQuery '$' getting "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when in my .JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code works when I write the JS in HTML like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Address Book</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="submitButton" type = "submit" value = "Save">
<script>
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
    console.log("result!");
});
</script>
</body>
```

but when I split it out into it's own .js file, the JS file doesn't recognise the JQuery '$' sign. This is how it currently looks in both HTML and JS (I added the .JS source to the HTML file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    **<script type="text/javascript" src="addressBook.js"></script>**
    <title>Address Book</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="submitButton" type = "submit" value = "Save">
</body>
```

and in the addressBook.js file:

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
    console.log("omg, you clicked me!");
```

I get the following error logged to the console when i click the button:

> $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
>   ^
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: move the `<script ..addressBook.js` below the jquery one

Comment: @LawrenceCherone well it sure looks like it comes after jQuery in the posted code.

Comment: Its looks that way, but I never trust user input and read between the lines. The error suggests the order and the `**` in the code suggest the OP added that after (for the question) and is not the real code.

Comment: Put the addressBook script after the html at the closing body tag. That sometimes works for me.

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete, your  code should be inside the `</body>` tag, what is with the `**<script` asterisks there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wat `selfagency` said + put the script tag before the end of the body.

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Address Book</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="addressBook.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

addressbook.js

```
$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
  console.log('result!');
});
```

The reason why the script tag in the head in this case doesn't work is because the button did not yet exist in the DOM when the `addressBook` script was run. Described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Moving the script tag to the end of the body did it. Thanks!

Comment: @MattCouthon I added a short explanation on the bottom and a link to read more about this problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to add the script before the end of the body.
It works after I created `addressBook.js` and change the `jquery`

```js
$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
 console.log("omg, you clicked me!");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="addressBook.js"></script>
    <title>Address Book</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
console.log("result!");
</script>
```

That is not proper syntax. It should be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
    console.log("result!");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function?